# how to create high trust SharePoint Add-ins?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, add-in, sharepoint-online

I am working on SharePoint add-in to create high trusted app. I am trying to create SharePoint add-in using certificates. I took [Create high-trust SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-high-trust-sharepoint-add-ins) as the reference. I have successfully generated .pfx and .cer file. Now, the next step is to configure SharePoint. I have opened my SharePoint Online Management Shell in Administrator mode. I executed these 2 lines successfully.

```
$publicCertPath = "C:\Certs\HighTrustSampleCert.cer"
$certificate = New-Object 
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($publicCertPath)
```

As soon as i entered `New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Name "HighTrustSampleCert" -Certificate $certificate`, I got the following exception.

```
New-SPTrustedRootAuthority : The term 'New-SPTrustedRootAuthority' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Name "HighTrustSampleCert" -Certificate $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-SPTrustedRootAuthority:String) [], 
      CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I don't know, why am I getting this error. Is there any other way to generate high trusted SharePoint add-in?

Comment: Have you loaded Sharepoint's cmdlets?

Comment: It appears you don't have the relevant module installed - once you know what module to use look into `import-module` and `install-module`

Comment: What module should I install?

Comment: Can you please help to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

High-trust add-in cannot be installed to Microsoft SharePoint Online, you need use low-trust for SharePoint online.